# Added methods to the Button (any view Class) in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, button

I have set up an android class to programmaticly set the text of a series button that was created in XML. In this class I would also like to create an identifier(numberid) for each instance of the button to later be used in an onclick method to be able to tell apart each button and also have differences for both.

I have used the below code and have set the buttons in the XML to use my class instead of the official button class

```
public final class numpadButton extends Button {
public int buttonNumber;

public numpadButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
     }


public void setButtonNumber(int buttonNumber) {
    this.buttonNumber = buttonNumber;

}

public int getButtonNumber() {
    return buttonNumber;
}
```

}

However extending the button class and adding the required methods ends up causing an error : android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class...

I know there may be other solutions and I am open to suggestion to the best way to accomplish my goal, However also I am interested in figure out how to make the way I talked about above work too.

Edit: XML

```
<macintyre.math.com.mathpractice.numpadButton style="@style/button" />
```

The style, although I don't see why this would be causing the problems.

```
 <style name="button">
        <item name="android:layout_width"> fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_weight"> 1</item>
    </style>



06-02 02:42:32.625    2428-2428/macintyre.math.com.mathpractice W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4d56b20) 06-02 02:42:32.629    2428-2428/macintyre.math.com.mathpractice E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: macintyre.math.com.mathpractice, PID: 2428
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class macintyre.math.com.mathpractice.numpadButton
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:603)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:839)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:745)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at macintyre.math.com.mathpractice.numberpad.onCreateView(numberpad.java:28)
            at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:866)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1040)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1142)
            at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4786)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at macintyre.math.com.mathpractice.AdditionFragment.onCreateView(AdditionFragment.java:19)
            at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
            at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
            at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:472)
            at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:446)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:568)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:839)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:745)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at macintyre.math.com.mathpractice.numberpad.onCreateView(numberpad.java:28)
            at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:866)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1040)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1142)
            at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4786)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at macintyre.math.com.mathpractice.AdditionFragment.onCreateView(AdditionFragment.java:19)
            at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
            at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Show the XML. Did you use the full package name of your button class?

Comment: That is not the problem currently, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: OK, show more of the stack trace too then.

Comment: okay I just added the whole log

Comment: why not use the button id? or use a tag? with a specified it? there are easier ways to this, why are you stressing yourself sir

Comment: +Elltx no reason. really more just a proof of concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elements inflated from layout file will use the 2nd constructor signature:

```
public numpadButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
```

Although you should implement all the constructor signatures:

```
public numpadButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr)
public numpadButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes)
```

Answer (score 1):

You must implement this constructor when inflating custom views from XML:

```
public View(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
```

From the official docs:

> Constructor that is called when inflating a view from XML.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#View(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet)